# Lwjgl GUI library

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, user-interface, lwjgl

I'm trying to make a little lwjgl GUI library by myself. I started again for 3 times now. My problem is that I fail to create a good OOP design.
I looked at the Java built in library Swing and AWT.
I dit read the codes, and studied the class design of Swing and AWT.
But I think this is not the correct way to make my own GUI library for lwjgl, because it's something with much differences.
One of my biggest problems I Always have in OO is that I can't reach a method. I think this is a general programming problem. For example, I have the following classes:

```
    class Container {

        private ArrayList<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();

        public void add(Component c) { // Accepts only Component objects, or child objects of Component

            this.components.add(c);
        }

        public volid paintAll() {

            for(int i = 0; i < this.components.size(); i++) {

                 // Not possible, the Component object has no method paintComponent(), the
                 // class which extends Component does. This can be a button, but it's stored as 
                 // a Component. So the method paintComponent "Does not exist" in this object,  
                 // but is does.
                 this.components.get(i).paintComponent(); // error
            }
        }
    }

class Component {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    /* methods of Component class */
}

class Button extends Component {

    private String text;

    public Button(String text) {

        this.text = text;
    }

    public void paintComponent() {

        /* Paint the button */

    }
}

// In Swing, the Component class has no method like paintComponent.
// The container can only reach the methods of Component, and can not use methods of
// classes which extends Component.
// That's my problem. How can I solve this?

Container container = new Container();
Button b = new Button("This is a button");
Container.add(b); // b "Is a" Component.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that *every* subclass of `Component` has a `paintComponent()` method. You can do that by declaring it as abstract in the superclass:

```
abstract class Component {

  /* fields of Component class */

  public abstract void paintComponent();

}
```

This will force every non-abstract subclass of `Component` to implement the method, otherwise the compiler will produce an error.

Swing does the same thing: `JComponent` has [a method `paint(Graphics)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29).

---

Aside: because `Component` is already present in the name of the class, it would be more customary to name the method `paint()` instead. This avoids repetition in the call, e.g. `myComponent.paint()` instead of `myComponent.paintComponent()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store your buttons as components, you can use the `instanceof` operator to check if they are actually buttons and then call any methods that only buttons have by casting them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.components.size(); i++) {
    if(components.get(i) instanceof Button){
        Button b = (Button)components.get(i);
        b.paintComponent(); //or any other methods that buttons have.
    }
    //treat it as a normal component;
}
```

Alternatively you could store your buttons seperately from your components which are not buttons and then not need to cast them.